# How to use getTableProps in react-table v7 with useTable

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to add className as a Table prop to my react-table and I did something like this:

```
 const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        prepareRow,
        page,
        pageCount,
        canPreviousPage,
        canNextPage,
        gotoPage,
        nextPage,
        previousPage,
        visibleColumns,
        state: { pageIndex, pageSize, sortBy },
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns: columns,
            data: handleDataObject,
            initialState: initialState,
            manualPagination: true,
            manualSortBy: manualSortBy,
            defaultCanSort: false,
            pageCount: getPageCount(),
            disableSortRemove: true,
            className: className,
        },
        useSortBy,
        useFlexLayout,
        useExpanded,
        usePagination
    );
```

But if I console log getTableProps() it returns only:

```
{ role: 'table',
style: {minWidth:0}}
```

So I am wondering where to place the props so they could be retrieved by getTableProps.

Thank you

Comment: I know that probably is not exactly the answer to your question, but you can pass your own properties as an argument to getTableProps. It accepts a function where you can set any table property, like width, border, etc. Maybe it help you or any other person with similar problem.

Comment: @jplindgren your paragraph of text is a good start, but how about expanding that into actual code, no matter how simple.